# prolog sort/4 undefined procedure built in

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to use a supposedly built in procedure in SWI-Prolog.
The procedure in question is [sort/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/4).

The thing is, when I try to use it in my program I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: sort/4
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         msort/2
ERROR:         sort/2
```

I don't understand because the documentation says its built-in, but Prolog doesn't know it. I really need to use this procedure

Would you know how to fix this issue ? I thought it was a matter of library and tried to add ":- use_module(library(lists))." at the beginning of my code but the situation remains the same.

Hope you can help me, have a good day

Comment: Please try figuring out what version of SWI-Prolog you are using. From the command line, that would be `$ swipl --version`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and got this "SWI-Prolog version 6.6.4 for amd64"
I am trying to upgrade to the latest version, hadn't thought of that...

Comment: Thank you it works now ! You saved me a long time of trouble, thanks a lot !!

Comment: Do you really need that generality. `sort/2` and `keysort/2` alone are already quite versatile - and certainly much faster.

Comment: @false: "sort/2 and keysort/2 ... certainly much faster" - not true, same speed.

Comment: @jschimpf: I see, so there is a fixed set of comparisons available.

Comment: @Boris: your comment should be an answer, really. Could serve as reference for future similar problems.

Comment: @false As it is at the moment, [`sort/4`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4) covers the majority of use-cases I have seen. Definitely more versatile than `sort/2`, `msort/2`, `keysort/2`, and requires less code to use.

Comment: @Boris: It is also highly permissive. Not like `keysort/2` which insists on a list of pairs, it takes whatever structure there is. Definitely not good for beginners.

Comment: @false I am too a beginner, and I have used it a non-negative number of times, without hurting myself too badly.

Comment: @Boris: You are #5 on tag Prolog.

Comment: @false I started answering question about 2 years ago on this tag because I wanted to learn Prolog. I would say I am a beginner. This question sounds like another beginner in Prolog: if they have any prior programming experience, `sort/4` is not going to be rocket science.

Comment: @false Just to add: me being #5 on tag Prolog (which I didn't realize until you pointed it out) says more about the Prolog tag than about me.

Comment: @false Yes i really need the sort/4 as I need an easy way to sort a structured term with respect to a specific dimension. I am indeed a beginner, I already struggle to make my floor planning problem solver work and don't want to reprogram existing procedures

Answer (score 2):

The `sort/4` predicate as documented [here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4) is relatively new. If you get the latest stable or development version of SWI-Prolog it should be available. It is a built-in, not a part of a library.